# Google autocomplete api for my site

Tags: api, autocomplete

Is it possible for google autocomplete api to specify to return results only for my site not for all sites? I see that there is param ds, but only purpose for that is to search in youtube. So how can I get autocomplete or maybe related or suggested search words only for single site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the very same thing and so far the only way I found to get this working is to create a custom search engine and then add it as a parameter to the autocomplete call:

```
http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=partner&gs_ri=partner&partnerid={0}&ds=cse
```

Where {0} is your custom search id

Certain features such as returning the results as XML don't work if you use the partner id but at least all the autocomplete results will be from your site.

You can also have multiple search engines and use different ones in different textboxes. Results are just a json string you parse.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.
Registered cse with my site, but autocomplete isn't working. I get empty results:
    window.google.ac.h(["riga",[],{"q":"XT8CH1U1GU9QibKh1oxuFGIVxD4","k":1}])
Maybe I need to wait a little bit?

Comment: This looks correct so far.. and yes it takes a bit of time to get the results showing up. Google will need to index your site first and that's kind of up to them. I get the very same result only with an array of json suggestions so I think it looks okay... you should start getting results soon

Comment: You can also use the custom search engine preview page to test the autocomplete. You should be getting identical results with google's autocomplete.